# how to make cell or column readonly using spreadsheetgear

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, spreadsheetgear

I am using the Spreadsheet gear component and need to select particular cells or columns in a worksheet so I can apply a read only property . How do we do?

Example : if there are 3 columns in excel sheet in that one column should be read only rest of them editable ...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

ProtectContents which is a property of IWorksheet + Locked which is a property of IRange

[Link to SpreadsheetGear Reference](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet~ProtectContents.html)